# How to hide/blur email address and phone number from content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm recently working on WP Project, where we need to blur the email address and phone number from content for all the logout users, and when they log in they can see the email address and phone number. I'm looking for its solution from hours but didn't able to find any.

**Experts help required**, I'm not sure if it can be done by JS or PHP?

Comment: Hi @Muhammed Ahmed, can you check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't blur the emails after you've already sent them, as anybody can just disable a css effect and view the email. What you should do is replace all the emails with a fake email placeholder such as `example@example.com` and then add a `filter: blur(3px);` on that elements CSS. This will blur the email and prevent anybody from viewing the email by disabling the CSS.

Since you didn't provide any PHP, I might recommend that you do a simple conditional such as:

```
if($isLoggedIn) {
   $email = $actualEmail;
   echo $email;
} else {
   $email = 'example@example.com';
   echo '<p class="hidden-email">'.$email.'</p>';
}
```

CSS:

```
.hidden-email {
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Comment: Actually its vendor site there will be a lot of emails and phone numbers, people listing their email address so the customer can contact them directly. What I want only login user can see it. 
Also, there are not any specific fields for this people can add them within the content, How can I detect the email within content section?

Comment: Yes this will do that, you will need to add that conditional to anywhere the email is being shown. In simple terms: Verify the user is logged in, and if they are show them the real email, if they arent show them a placeholder email. However you decide to do it add a CSS class that blurs it and you will get your desired result. Wordpress has a function `is_user_logged_in()`. That might be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works in my case as the email or phone number will be in the content section, there is not any specific field for that. BTW, Thanks

Comment: Are you developing and changing the wordpress files, or are you simply using wordpress's built in editor? This solution will not work with Wordpress's visual editor as it can not nativly run PHP. If you are talking about using the visual editor, I suggest intsalling a plugin that lets you run PHP within the file, then you can use this solution. You can also check here to see if you can modify any files at a core level: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Files